# ViewModel with two lists, how can I filter the content of one into different unordered lists in the view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'd like to start off with an apology for the poorly worded question and if this or a similar question has been answered before, but I've spent the entire day and large parts of yesterday looking for an answer with no luck so hopefully this will be ok.

I'm a complete novice to MVC (and quite new to programming in general) and am working on a "TV Guide" website, currently with hardcoded schedules etc just to get design and such in place and to learn MVC. On my index-page I will list every show, divided per channel, and as such I have this in my controller. (Trying to show only the most relevant parts)

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {                       
        List<ChannelVM> channelList = db.Channel.Select(x => new ChannelVM
        {
            Id = x.Id,
            Name = x.Name,
            ...
        }).ToList();

        List<ScheduleVM> scheduleList = db.Schedule.Select(x => new ScheduleVM
        {
            ...
            ChannelId = x.ChannelId,
            ChannelName = x.Channel.Name,
            ...
        }).ToList();           

        var indexModel = new IndexVM
        {
            ChannelList = channelList,
            ScheduleList = scheduleList
        };                       

        return View(indexModel);
    }
```

In my View, I have:

```
@model DagensTV.Models.ViewModels.IndexVM

...

@if (Model != null)
{
    foreach (var item in Model.ChannelList)
    {
        ...

            <ul>
                @foreach (var show in Model.ScheduleList)
                {
                    <li>
                        ...

                    </li>
                }
            </ul>
        ...
    }
}
```

Currently only 4 channels are hardcoded with data in a local database. Schedule is the table that has all the info I want show, and it includes a foreign key to Channel, ChannelId. With the code shown above, it creates the 4 unordered lists on the view and fills the section from Model.ChannelList correctly with the logo and so on, but in the actual schedule I of course get everything listed for every channel. I've "solved it" by making a change in the view as seen below:

```
@foreach (var show in Model.ScheduleList.Where(x => x.ChannelName == item.Name))
```

However that is not a solution I'm satisfied with as I've been told over and over to avoid that kind of code in the View, and to do everything in the controller.

In the controller I've tried adding some lambda to "filter" things similar to the solution above from the view, but to no avail.

I'm at a loss on how to proceed now so my question is, how can I filter the scheduleList so that the shows with a ChannelID of 1 go to one unordered list in the view, the shows with a ChannelID of 2 go to another etc? Any help is greatly appreciated even if it's just a nudge in the right direction. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a property in your `ChannelViewModel` to hold the `Schedule` of the channel, and from the controller action you would return each `Channel` with it's `Schedules` populated and you would then need to only loop through those.

Your `ChannelVM` would need to be like:

```
public class ChannelVM
{

   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
   ......
   ......
   public List<ScheduleVM> Schedules {get;set;}

}
```

It would be something like:

```
List<ChannelVM> channelList = db.Channel.Select(x => new ChannelVM
{
    Id = x.Id,
    Name = x.Name,
    Schedules = db.Schedule.Where(s=>s.ChannelId == x.Id)
                              .Select(schedule => new ScheduleVM
                                {


                                  ...
                                }).ToList();
```

Now in your view you would be doing something like:

```
foreach (var item in Model.ChannelList)
{
    ...

    <ul>
        @foreach (var show in item.ScheduleList)
        {
            <li>
               ...

            </li>
        }
    </ul>
    ...
}
```

Note: This is just to give you the approach idea how you can do it, you would need to adjust your ViewModel to get it working.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you very much! Will try to incorporate it in my code now and see how it works out. :)

Comment: Using this as a startingpoint worked wonders and I got it working, thank you again so much! Accepted answer, sadly my upvote of your comment won't register due to my account-status however. :)